# Spring boot can't mapp to the links in HTML

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring boot starter project with maving pluging,
spring boot can't know the links in my HTML templates.
this is my controller :

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Demoproject2Application {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "/html/Authentification";
}
}
```

and this is the Authentification.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Authentification</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />
```

and  this is the error :

```
2015-02-19 14:29:58.749  INFO 5136 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].    [localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

2015-02-19 14:29:58.749  INFO 5136 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-02-19 14:29:58.774  INFO 5136 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 25 ms
2015-02-19 14:29:59.086  WARN 5136 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/style2.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-02-19 14:30:00.813  WARN 5136 --- [nio-8090-exec-4]o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound

here is a snapshot of the hierarchy of my project :

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11011221_811266045595770_3095529215585152558_n.jpg?oh=a51a1196651bd62c81a76679869c1bdd&oe=558FD62B&**gda**=1431221666_e2d5202a80db81801ed9903c48014130](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11011221_811266045595770_3095529215585152558_n.jpg?oh=a51a1196651bd62c81a76679869c1bdd&oe=558FD62B&__gda__=1431221666_e2d5202a80db81801ed9903c48014130)

Comment: The INFO message is just indicating that /css/style2.css is not found and will result in a 404. Without knowing how you organized your files in the project it is hard to tell where your issue actually is.

Comment: here is a snapshot of the hierarchy of my project :

 https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11011221_811266045595770_3095529215585152558_n.jpg?oh=a51a1196651bd62c81a76679869c1bdd&oe=558FD62B&gda=1431221666_e2d5202a80db81801ed9903c48014130

Comment: I tried to put the file style2.css and Authentification.html in the same directory but still the same error " o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound" I didn't get what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't changed any defaults it should be served when you put it into `src/main/resources/static/css/style2.css`. Please see [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).